# Arrow position incorrect based on "side:['top','bottom']"

Tags: jquery, css, tooltipster

I have implemented the latest version of tool tipster plugin at [takeitdown](http://www.takeitdown.tt) ( scroll to "supporters" and click on names) and I have set the following options

```
{
contentCloning: true,
trigger: 'click',
theme: 'tooltipster-borderless',
maxWidth: 320,
minWidth: 130,
side: ['top', 'bottom'],
}
```

but when the tooltip displays the "arrow" position is badly off. How is this happening and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by Add some additional styles to the element via the class

Comment: As you wish but my solution is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the tooltip on the span that contains the name, not on the container div which is larger than the name.